# Can I use my Android tablet charger for the PlayBook?

Tags: battery-charging, charger

I got a BlackBerry PlayBook and it came with the wrong charger plug. It's for the US that I can't use here in Germany.

Can I use my Android tablet charger for the PlayBook instead?

The information on the chargers are similiar but for the output it's a bit different: (They both say 5V but than 1.8 instead of 1.5)

PlayBook charger output: 5V = **1.8A**

Android tablet charger output: 5V = **1.5A**

Thanks for any feedback.

Comment: This question is not on topic for this site. But the rating is the maximum current that the charger can supply, so it may not work.

Comment: Where can I ask this question? Are there any stackexchange boards available?

Comment: maybe SuperUser can be appropriate

Comment: @Nick, It should work just fine as LieRyan said but for a differnt reason. The device will stop pulling current when the charger voltage sags so it will self limit to what the charger can supply. It may charge a bit slower.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it may charge slower due to the lower amperage, but it should work just fine. USB standard specifies that the minimum available amperage be 500mAh in data transfer ports (raised to 0.9mAh in USB3.0), and at least 1.5mAh should be available in dedicated charging and charging+data port. Assuming both device and charger implemented the standard correctly, then it should work or at least it should not damage the device if 1.5A is insufficient.

Comment: this question is off topic and has been closed but I would like to share one thing with you. The USB spec has a separate spec for chargers. I discuss the divisions [here](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/5581/230).