# USB wall charger current question

Tags: usb, charger

I have a USB wall charger with this text on it:

> INPUT: 100-240V 50/60Hz 0.5A
>
> OUTPUT: 5.2VDC 2.0A 10.4W

I'm building a circuit I want to power via USB and I calculated it would sink 500mA from VCC. Can I use this charger for it? Will it force the current to be 2A and fry my circuit? Does "OUTPUT 2A" mean "2A source" or "2A max sink"?

Also, if it does force the current, how can I regulate it in a nice and cheap way? Do I have to fuse/polyswitch it?

Comment: Its a voltage source, not a current source. It does not 'force' any current into your circuit. If you need more than 500mA, you need some kind of resistor arrangment. This question has some good information about it: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/123172/what-is-the-ideal-way-to-handle-data-pins-d-and-d-on-a-usb-power-adapter-to-be

Comment: @Linkyyy How does a resistor arrangement give more current?

Comment: @Chu: I was assuming it was a USB2 charger, which you need different kind of resistor arrangements between the data pins to trick the charger into thinking its a matched phone, and that it can draw more than 500mA. The resistor setting is proprietary and depends what manufactor it is, samsung, sony, apple.. Some supports USB BC though, so it is more standardized.