# Minimum current to charge a 5v device?

Tags: power, usb, battery-charging, charging

I'm trying to use a DC-DC converter to charge a mobile phone.

This is the converter....[TRACO 12v-5v converter](https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/isolated-dc-dc-converters/4667051/)

The converter is relatively low power, (5w) and can supply a maximum of 1amp. Testing with both a USB voltmeter and a multimeter indicates that the device is correctly wired and producing 5v.

However, when I plug in my iPhone (or tablet or any other mobile device) there's no sign of any actually charging taking place. (I would normally expect to see a little lightening strike zig-zag symbol appear on the battery)

Is this because there is a minimum current requirement to power the mobile device?
Is the device likely to be not charging at all? or is it probably charging ok, but at a very slow rate?

I know that if I were charging a lead-acid battery at a very low current then the battery would still charge, albeit very slowly.

If there *is* a minimum current requirement for my mobile device, what's it likely to be? I know I can buy higher current 5v supplies, but would prefer to know exactly what I need before hand rather than just buying DC-DC converters on a trial and error basis.

UPDATE - I have left the 'data +' and 'data -' unconnected, and simply connected ground to ground, and Vcc to 5v. My understanding (perhaps wrong) is that a USB device should be able to charge itself with this configuration. It's only if attempting to fast-charge a device 'data +' and 'data -' need to be connected to anything.

Comment: How does *your* charger connector look like?

Comment: It's a USB 'A' connector

Comment: Did you check this USB A receptable with another stripped USB A plug if the 5 volt is still there?

Comment: Yes - I've measured the voltage on the red/black wires on a stripped down USB lead, I've also used a USB voltage tester

Comment: you need resistors on the USB fro the phone to recognise it as a charger

Comment: Maybe some of the information collected here might be of help for your cause: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/123172/what-is-the-ideal-way-to-handle-data-pins-d-and-d-on-a-usb-power-adapter-to-be  Summarized the termination of D+ and D- matters and the correct termination depends sometimes on the device to be charged. Especially Apple seems to give you a hard time there.