# 12v Input LM2596 Step Down Module to USB 5.2V is Slow Charging

Tags: voltage-regulator, automotive

I am trying to use this regulator module (LM2596) to regulate my car's 12V power (constant from fuse port), and use the LM2596 output set to 5.2V to charge my phone (LG G6) but get the slow charging warning (6hs xx mins to full).

I presume the output Amperage can meet whats specified ~2-3A, but obviously something is wrong.  I gutted a USB extension cable to solder to the output of the regulator.

What Am I missing?  Is this module capable of doing what I want?

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/123172/what-is-the-ideal-way-to-handle-data-pins-d-and-d-on-a-usb-power-adapter-to-be

Comment: If you still have it, I would be interested in the schema of your circuit, as I'm looking exactly for that: forcing a _slow_ charge to preserve battery life.

Comment: @Toni Homedes i Saun ... I don't really have a schematic besides Power + and - solder points to the LM2596 + - inputs.
If I recall, many cheap USB cables were not configured to the Android or Apple physical requirements, thus providing a slower (less amps) charge to the device.
I'm not sure why the phones go into this slow charge mode without the resistors etc... 
Perhaps there are some commercial solutions for you in forcing a slow charge, as I've not tested nor rated the Amps of any of this posted scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my configuration using this phone,
I was able to twist connect the two data wires together, which then my phone then stopped the naggy slow charge message.

I am aware that Apple uses a resistor across the data lines for their phones.

Link provided in comments was supplementary to my goal.
Thanks