# Android USB OTG

Tags: android

How to measure voltage at micro usb port on android with multimeter???I connected black wire to the ground pin and red wire to VBUS but is not showing anything on display.
Connector is connected to Micro B port and Micro B connector is on the cable end.

Comment: Is there a reason to ask this again? Without really clarifying anything?  Duplicate of 206105.  And, assuming that you have the cable plugged into the phone, and are measuring the other end, your phone isn't a current source... it is a consumer.

Comment: Android is an OS. Presumably you mean a piece of hardware running Android, what is it?

Answer (score 0):

Normal cell phone or tablet usb ports will not output a voltage on the usb VUSB/VCC or GND pins. OTG usb ports, **if supported by the phone**, need to be enabled by grounding the ID or Sense pin, before it will attempt to output 5V on the VUSB line.

[image]

**A USB OTG adapter cable is typically needed**. As a test, I hooked up a OTG adapter cable and a non-enumerating usb voltage tester (Essentially a multimeter) to a Samsung Galaxy S4 and got 5.1V volts showing up.

Comment: Even with OTG cable it will not be possible to check the voltage with a multimeter. OTG powers the slave device for a split second and cuts the power off if no attempts to enumerate were made. You'll need an oscilloscope to see that.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev source?

Comment: I know that from experience with TI SoCs. I assume TI is following the USB spec.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev I just connected a OTG adapter and a non-enumerating usb voltage/amperage tester (USB Charge Doctor) with my Samsung phone, and it shows up 5.13V for several minutes now.

Comment: That's entirely possible. Here's [my experience](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/165806/how-to-configure-usb-otg-as-power-supply). Let me correct myself: "it **may** not be possible to see that with a multimeter".

Comment: The activation of the charge pump is usually under software control, typically at kernel level.  Normally this responds to the mode pin but it could be written to consider other factors.

Comment: Only with OTG adapter and a non-enumerating usb voltage/amperage tester (USB Charge Doctor) ??????

Comment: Where can I buy usb charge doctor???

Comment: @Pavle the usb charge doctor is a generic usb voltage meter (Check eBay or google for `usb voltage meter`). Its literally the same thing as a multimeter you use to measure the voltage. There is nothing special about it other than being convenient to use.

Comment: Why is no possible to see usb voltage with a multimeter???

Comment: S3 Neo otg voltage: 0.00 volts,
S3 OTG VOLTAGE: 5.15 volts

Comment: Does the Neo support otg? Samsung tends to skimp out on the bargain phones.

Comment: S3 Neo supports otg with external power supply.